# Chat unavailable from navigation bar

Tags: bug, support, chat

<strike>I've reached a point on a question that it's better to use the Chat system instead of comments, but can't for some reason.</strike>

Should the Chat option be available for the site yet, or is that once the site is 
public?

It appears the chat button from the "StackExchange" menu item redirects to 3D Printing SE chat window, so is that a bug?

Comment: it is: http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/q/7/54

Comment: Thanks, maybe its a bug from the navigation bar? Mine redirects to 3D Printing SE.

Comment: It doesn't redirect to 3D printing for me, it directs to http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=iot.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is it maybe a user setting then?